# Tic-Tac-Toe TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python-2.7

I am programming a Tic-Tac-Toe game. I have most of the program done. But I keep getting the following error and I don't understand what I am doing wrong. I have tried formatting it differently.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Akshay Sastry/Documents/CS 303E/Tic-Tac-Toe.py", line 66, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/Akshay Sastry/Documents/CS 303E/Tic-Tac-Toe.py", line 3, in main
    while isWinner(board) == 0 and movesLeft(board) == True:
  File "C:/Users/Akshay Sastry/Documents/CS 303E/Tic-Tac-Toe.py", line 20, in isWinner
    if (b[0][0]=='x') and (b[0][0]==b[0][1]==b[0][2]):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

This is my code:

```
def main():
    board = makeBoard()
    while isWinner(board) == 0 and movesLeft(board) == True:
        printBoard(board)
        p1row, p1col = input("Enter a row and column for x: ")
        board[p1row][p1col] = 'x'
        if isWinner(board) == 0 and movesLeft(board) == True:
            printBoard(board)
            p2row, p2col = input("Enter a row and column for o: ")
            board[p2row][p2col] = 'o'
    if isWinner(board) != 0:
        print isWinner(board), 'won!'
    else:
        print 'Tie game.'

def makeBoard():
    board = [['*','*','*'],['*','*','*'],['*','*','*']]

def isWinner(b):
    if (b[0][0]=='x') and (b[0][0]==b[0][1]==b[0][2]):
        return 'x'
    elif (b[1][0]=='x') and (b[1][0]==b[1][1]==b[1][2]):
        return 'x'
    elif (b[2][0]=='x') and (b[2][0]==b[1][1]==b[2][2]):
        return 'x'
    elif (b[0][0]=='x') and (b[0][0]==b[1][0]==b[2][0]):
        return 'x'
    elif (b[0][1]=='x') and (b[0][1]==b[1][1]==b[2][1]):
        return 'x'
    elif (b[0][2]=='x') and (b[0][2]==b[1][2]==b[2][2]):
        return 'x'
    elif (b[0][0]=='x') and (b[0][0]==b[1][1]==b[2][2]):
        return 'x'
    elif (b[0][2]=='x') and (b[0][2]==b[1][1]==b[2][0]):
        return 'x'
    elif (b[0][0]=='o') and (b[0][0]==b[0][1]==b[0][2]):
        return 'o'
    elif (b[1][0]=='o') and (b[1][0]==b[1][1]==b[1][2]):
        return 'o'
    elif (b[2][0]=='o') and (b[2][0]==b[1][1]==b[2][2]):
        return 'o'
    elif (b[0][0]=='o') and (b[0][0]==b[1][0]==b[2][0]):
        return 'o'
    elif (b[0][1]=='o') and (b[0][1]==b[1][1]==b[2][1]):
        return 'o'
    elif (b[0][2]=='o') and (b[0][2]==b[1][2]==b[2][2]):
        return 'o'
    elif (b[0][0]=='o') and (b[0][0]==b[1][1]==b[2][2]):
        return 'o'
    elif (b[0][2]=='o') and (b[0][2]==b[1][1]==b[2][0]):
        return 'o'
    else:
        return 0

def printBoard(board):
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            print board[i][j],
        print

def movesLeft(board):
    if board[0].count("*") != 0 or board[1].count("*") != 0 or board[2].count("*") != 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `makeBoard()` function returns `None`. You should make it like this:

```
def makeBoard():
    return [['*','*','*'],['*','*','*'],['*','*','*']]
```

Comment: Wow! Cant' believe I missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your `isWinner` function can be made 3x smaller, as follows

```
def isWinner(b):
    for i in range(3):
        if (b[i][0] != '*') and (b[i][0]==b[i][1]==b[i][2]): # all rows
            return b[i][0]
        if (b[0][i] != '*') and (b[0][i]==b[1][i]==b[2][i]): # all cols
            return b[0][i]
    if (b[0][0] != '*') and (b[0][0]==b[1][1]==b[2][2]): # tl-br diag
        return b[0][0]
    elif (b[0][2] != '*') and (b[0][2]==b[1][1]==b[2][0]): # bl-tr diag
        return b[0][2]
    else:
        return 0
```

For a larger board such as connect 4, however, you'd iterate over all points on the board and write a method that checked in a loop an arbitrary distance in every direction, rather than hard-coding every place a row can be in.